# $\phi$-entropies, $\phi$-divergences and classical entropy recovery

Tags: probability-distributions, it.information-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\Ent{End}$The $\phi$ entropy is defined as $\Ent_{\phi}[X]= \mathbb{E}[\phi (X)]-\phi(\mathbb{E}[ X])$ where $X$ is a random variable and $\phi$ is a convex function ($\Ent_{\phi}[X] \geq 0$). By choosing $\phi(x)=x^2$ we get  $\Ent_{\phi}[X]=\operatorname{Var}(X)$. If $\phi(x)=x\log x$ and $X=\frac{dv}{d\mu} $ (Radon–Nikodym derivative) we get $\Ent_{\phi}[X]= D_{\text{KL}}(v\Vert\mu)$. Can we recover the classical entropy $H(X)= -\mathbb{E}[\log p(X)]$ in a similar way?

[Edit: added a minus sign in the definition of $H(X)$ -AK]

Comment: You were missing a minus sign in the definition of the classical entropy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The choice $\phi(x)=x\log(x)$ yields an entropy distinct from Shannon entropy. See p. 94 of *[Concentration Inequalities: A Nonasymptotic Theory of Independence](https://doi.org/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199535255.001.0001)* by Boucheron, Lugosi, Massart.

The two entropies are related but distinct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want $\phi(x) = \log1/x$. Then $$Ent_\phi(P(X)) = E[\log P(X)] - \log[EP(x)] = H(X) - \log(1) = H(X).$$